# Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateNullablerequired does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

What actually wrong here?

When i am going to submit my form this error appears. Please give me the solution.

Comment: Please can you post your code, and show the line where the error is being produced

Comment: add code please

Comment: This problem has solved!!

Comment: Hey. Please also post your code whenever you fixed it. Anyone else could learn of it easier, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got the solutin!!!
I just forgot to put "|" between Nullable and Required
this is the solution  'sometimes|nullable|string'

Comment: thank you for your activations on this website. are there any other communities in the world like this to discuss or ask a question about laravel? except for laracast?

Answer (score 11):

I solve by changing number to numeric because there no laravel validation name as **number**

**Before**

```
'required|number|max:10'
```

**After**

```
 'required|numeric|max:10'
```

Comment: second time that this answer helped me.thanks. i dont know why use number for validation

Comment: This worked. Not sure why laravel doesn't use Number either. makes no sense. Even javascript uses number, would be standard. Thanks again!